# c# Regex named groups access non existent group name

Tags: c#, regex

What happens if I access `Match.Groups["blahblah"]` when `blahblah` is not present in the regex (or is an optional group). It does not throw an exception, how do I then check if the group does not exist?

One way could be

```
Match.Groups["blahblah"].Value == ""
```

is it the preferred way?

Comment: `Match.Groups["blahblah"].Success`

Comment: `not present in the regex (or is an optional group). It does not throw an exception` A group name is a hash key. At runtime, this key  Match.Groups["`blahblah`"] is checked for existence. Should it throw an exception if it doesn't ?  What if the part of your code that tries to access it never gets run during development. Want it to throw an exception in production ? Also, if a group is _optional_ it is defined in the regex, so it exists. Bottom line is you should know your regex and what to expect from it.